# Error: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Percent)

Tags: apex, trigger

I created a custom field in both opportunity and quote object named discount percentage. I needed to map the discount entered in the opportunity object into the quote object. So I made a field update workflow and the error is Error: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Percent).

PS. the fields are both Percent and 18,0
please help.

[image]

Comment: Change Return Type of your Formula Field, AND Why you are assigning value in formula field ?

Answer (score 1):

What you have added is comparing two values with each other. There is no need to refer quote Discount_Percentage__c fields. You require Opportunity field as shown below

```
Opportunity.Discount_Percentage__c
```

and if you want to put same value on quote as well. You can use formula field instead of workflow field update. It will work in same way and show you exact value what you have in Opportunity.Discount_Percentage__c field